# Ruby Hash destructive vs. non-destructive method

Tags: ruby, hash

Could not find a previous post that answers my question...I'm learning how to use destructive vs. non-destructive methods in Ruby.   I found an answer to the exercise I'm working on (destructively adding a number to hash values), but I want to be clear on why some earlier solutions of mine did not work.  Here's the answer that works:

```
  def modify_a_hash(the_hash, number_to_add_to_each_value)
    the_hash.each { |k, v| the_hash[k] = v + number_to_add_to_each_value}
  end
```

These two solutions come back as non-destructive (since they all use "each" I cannot figure out why.  To make something destructive is it the equals sign above that does the trick?):

```
  def modify_a_hash(the_hash, number_to_add_to_each_value)
    the_hash.each_value { |v| v + number_to_add_to_each_value}
  end

  def modify_a_hash(the_hash, number_to_add_to_each_value)
    the_hash.each { |k, v| v + number_to_add_to_each_value}
  end
```

Comment: In your last two methods a number is being calculated, but then simply discarded, for each element of `the_hash.values` and `the_hash`, respectively. Both methods return `the_hash`, which is unchanged. You need to stuff the values you are computing into a new hash. @tadman shows one way; another (for #2) is `h = {}; the_hash.each { |k,v| h[k] = v + num_to_add }; h` or, more Ruby-like, `the_hash.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h[k] = v + num_to_add }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms "destructive" and "non-destructive" are a bit misleading here. Better is to use the conventional "in-place modification" vs. "returns a copy" terminology.

Generally methods that modify in-place have `!` at the end of their name to serve as a warning, like `gsub!` for String. Some methods that pre-date this convention do not have them, like `push` for Array.

The `=` performs an assignment within the loop. Your other examples don't actually do anything useful since `each` returns the original object being iterated over regardless of any results produced.

If you wanted to return a copy you'd do this:

```
def modify_a_hash(the_hash, number_to_add)
  Hash[
    the_hash.collect do |k, v|
      [ k, v + number_to_add ]
    end
  ]
end
```

That would return a copy. The inner operation `collect` transforms key-value pairs into new key-value pairs with the adjustment applied. No `=` is required since there's no assignment.

The outer method `Hash[]` transforms those key-value pairs into a proper Hash object. This is then returned and is independent of the original.

Generally a non-destructive or "return a copy" method needs to create a new, independent version of the thing it's manipulating for the purpose of storing the results. This applies to String, Array, Hash, or any other class or container you might be working with.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this slightly different example will be helpful.

We have a hash:

```
2.0.0-p481 :014 > hash
 => {1=>"ann", 2=>"mary", 3=>"silvia"}
```

Then we iterate over it and change all the letters to the uppercase:

```
2.0.0-p481 :015 > hash.each { |key, value| value.upcase! }
 => {1=>"ANN", 2=>"MARY", 3=>"SILVIA"}
```

The original hash has changed because we used upcase! method.

Compare to method without ! sign, that doesn't modify hash values:

```
2.0.0-p481 :017 > hash.each { |key, value| value.downcase }
=> {1=>"ANN", 2=>"MARY", 3=>"SILVIA"}
```